# Microk8s on Linux - Wither /etc/kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I've fired up a 6 node (3 Control Plane and 3 workers) Microk8s cluster on my Mac (for fun, shiggles and hopefully eventual profit) and it's seemingly happily running.

Question is,I'm now reading Kubernetes documentation that talks about modifying files in `/etc/kubernetes`, yet I'm not seeing that folder on my first control plane server.

Am I missing something? Does Microk8s (being a snap) keep this stuff elsewhere?

#### Edit

As @Glen Yu pointed out below, there are folders under the `/var/snap/microk8s` folder, but what I'm looking for specifically are files like the `kube-apiserver.yaml` file as referenced in this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/

Comment: Does [this](https://microk8s.io/docs/configuring-services) help?  As you suspected, it's under a snap directory

Comment: Sorta - but no. I'm trying to locate the analog to the kube-apiserver.yaml file - I'm not seeing that in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think there is no direct analog. [This](https://devshell.io/kubernetes-secrets-in-microk8s/) page seems to indicate that the best one can hope for are the `microk8s` files.

In my case, since I need to work on some secrets, it sounds like one has to first run `pgrep -an kubelite` then edit the file specified in the `--apiserver-args-file` argument (for 1.26 this seems to be `/var/snap/microk8s/4959/args/kube-apiserver`) and add the following line: `--encryption-provider-config=/path/to/k8s-crypto.yaml` and then restart the cluster with `sudo systemctl restart snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite`